# Find and replace in Google Spreadsheet using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, google-sheets, find-replace

I would like to use the Google Spreadsheet Find and Replace function with the "Search using regular expressions" function activated to do a search and replace in my document.

Use case: Some of my cells contain erroneous linefeed characters at the end (leftovers from paste operation by some of the editors).

I'm using the following pattern to successfully find the cells

> .*\012$

Is there some syntax for the "Replace with" field that lets me replace the cell's content by the string I found minus the `\012` character at the end?

The Google Spreadsheet documentation does not contain any relevant information. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754?hl=en

[Here's a screenshot of the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AGz1.png)

Comment: Can't you use`\012$` and replace with empty string?

Comment: That would remove all line breaks from all cells. We've used them intentionally in some places. Just the ones at the end are definitely wrong.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use a capturing group `(...)` in the pattern around the part you want to keep, and use a `$1` backreference in the replacement:

```
(.*)\012$
```

to replace with `$1`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lM1aJ7/1).